# Median in a list of n elements

Tags: python, list, median

I'm trying to determine the median of a list of n elements and I just can't see what I am doing wrong.

I have `sorted(list)` so that the elements are in the right order but I get a median of `5.0` instead of the correct `4.5`.

My code looks like this.

```
def median(lista):
    median_even1 = 0
    median_even2 = 0
    median_sum = 0
    median_average = 0
    if len(lista) % 2 == 0:
        sorted(lista)
        median_even1 += lista[(len(lista)/2)]
        median_even2 += lista[(len(lista)/2 - 1)]
        median_sum = median_even1 + median_even2
        median_average = (median_sum) // (2.0)
        return median_average
    else:
        sorted(lista)
        return lista[(len(lista) / 2)]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sorted()` isn't in place, it returns a new sorted list. Either reassign it (`lista = sorted(lista)`) or use `list.sort()` instead (`lista.sort()`).

Comment: Note that this code still has several mistakes, at least one of which causes a traceback (on Python 3, so I assume this is Python 2... still, produces the wrong answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can streamline a lot of that code while fixing the errors (`sorted()` not operating in place, `len(lista)/2` being a floating-point number and therefore not a valid index value, using `//` with a float literal and presumably expecting a precise float, and so on).

```
def median(lista):
    lista = sorted(lista)
    half = len(lista)//2
    if half == len(lista)/2:
        return (lista[half]+lista[half-1])/2.
    return lista[half]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 5//2.0
2.0
>>> float(5)/2.0
2.5
```

//2.0 doesn't work in this case